# Get probe names from HTAFeatureSet expression data

Tags: r, expression, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I would like to know how can I obtain *probenames* for each row in a `HTAFeatureSet@assayData$exprs` object in R.

When I perform the RMA to this object I get an *Expressionset* with rows indicating *probenames* and columns indicating array names.

I would like to use this matrix but before normalizing expression data, I would like to obtain a matrix with rows indicating probenames and columns indicating array names, but with raw expression data; however, the *HTAFeatureSet* just indicates array names but not *probenames* (the rows are called 1,2,3,4....).

Answer (score 1):

Just exploring the `oligo::rma` source code, you find the hidden function `stArrayPmInfo`.

```
probe_df <- oligo::stArrayPmInfo(your_HTAFeatureSet, target = "core")
```

First column is the probe index, second is the probe name.